# A more efficient way to manage partitions

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I'm almost running out of space due to the .Private files.

[image]

Given that I have a lot of unused space in blkOp1 & blkOp2

[image]

would there be a better way of organising where I place the encryption files?

With the Disk Usage Analyzer, I can see that the .Private files are 16GB

[image]

of my 23GB drive.

[image]

Comment: A lot? Really? You don't have even space enough on these two blkOp partitions togheter!...

Comment: There's nothing that you can do except delete unnecessary files, because your SSD is too small.

Comment: @heynnema do you mean unnecessary .Private files? Because I also see that dev/mapper is full. As you can tell I am not familiar with Linux file systems.

Comment: What does the `Disk Usage Analyzer` say about your space?

Comment: Isn't mmcblkOp an **SD Card** inserted in your computer ? With a LUKS encrypted partition and `/boot/` and `/boot/efi` partitions.

Comment: These .Private files is a **folder** with your encrypted data. Move some bigger size data like pictures, movies, music to an external device. Or buy a bigger SSD/HDD. 24G is just not enough for a modern System.